# Flutter : Fetch Cloud Firestore data but no results

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I'm quite new on Flutter and I need your help on a simple (i think) issue. I need to retrieve data from Firestore cloud. Unfortunately, i still have my Circularprogress widget that tells me that my snapshot is null while i a collection set up and datas inside:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class RacketDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data;
  RacketDetail({required this.data});

  @override
  _RacketDetailState createState() => _RacketDetailState(data);
}

class _RacketDetailState extends State<RacketDetail> {
  String data;
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore;
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> itemlist;
  _RacketDetailState(this.data)
      : firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance,
        itemlist = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('SyntheseProduits')
            .where('Designation', isEqualTo: data)
            .snapshots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(data),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff103572),
        actions: <Widget>[],
      ),
      body: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: itemlist,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null)
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      Text(
                        data + " No snapshot",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs.map(
                      (document) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 35,
                              ),
                              CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 121,
                                backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                                    'assets/Images/Img_' + data + '.jpeg'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 45,
                              ),
                              Card(
                                elevation: 7.0,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    ListTile(
                                      leading: IconButton(
                                        color: Color(0xfffc9303),
                                        icon: Icon(
                                            Icons.chrome_reader_mode_rounded),
                                        onPressed: () {},
                                      ),
                                      title: Text(
                                        document['Designation'].toString(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          color: Color(0xfffc9303),
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ).toList(),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If it can help, please find also a screenshot of my [IOS Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfB94.png) and my [Firestore collection view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REnoF.png)

Thanks in advance for your eyes and help ! :)

Comment: If you remove the `where` clause do you get any results?

Comment: Hi @Nolence, thanks for you reply, unfortunately i still have the same result.

Comment: I finally solve it ! The issue was caused by the cloud firestore rule :

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

it was on false ....

Comment: Awesome ! Also sorry, didn't see your response till now